# cant seem to include Twitter Bootstrap in Yii

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I just started using Yii today, and i'm trying to get bootstrap to work.

i tried following these instructions http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html#setup but it still doesn't work. my **/protected/config/main.php** looks like this.

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// Define a path alias for the Bootstrap extension as it's used internally.
// In this example we assume that you unzipped the extension under protected/extensions.
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Site',
    'theme'=>'bootstrap', // requires you to copy the theme under your themes directory

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => '', //Enter Your Password Here
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),

        ),

        /*'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),*/

        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'admin@blablabla',
    ),
);
```

i downloaded and unzipped this http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/files/yii-bootstrap-2.1.0.r355.zip into my **/protected/extensions/bootstrap** and the folders in the bootstrap folder are:

1. assets
2. components
3. form
4. gii
5. theme
6. widgets

i read somewhere i need to put `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();` somewhere. but i have no idea which file to put it in. i tried putting it into **/protected/config/main.php** but i get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CWebApplication.bootstrap" is not defined.' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/framework/base/CComponent.php:130 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/framework/base/CModule.php(105): CComponent->__get('bootstrap') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/protected/config/main.php(10): CModule->__get('bootstrap') #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/framework/base/CApplication.php(133): require('/Applications/X...') #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/framework/YiiBase.php(125): CApplication->__construct('/Applications/X...') #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/framework/YiiBase.php(98): YiiBase::createApplication('CWebApplication', '/Applications/X...') #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/index.php(13): YiiBase::createWebApplication('/Applications/X...') #6 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev2/framework/base/CComponent.php on line 130
```

Comment: Instead of registering it that way try just adding it to your preload:

Comment: try this: `'preload'=>array('log','bootstrap'),`

Comment: In addition to Pitchinnate's advice (which should solve your immediate problem), I do not believe that extension is maintained any longer - you may have better luck with the yiistrap ext:  http://www.getyiistrap.com/

Comment: @PrplHaz4 thanks, that worked. but just out of curiosity where do i put that code @Pitchinnate?

Comment: @user2636556, that preload code goes in config/main.php (there is probably already an existing entry there for 'log' - as shown in Pitchinnate's example)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();` where you want to use bootstrap. Usually it is main layout.

Add `<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>` to **/protected/layouts/main.php** somewhere in `<head>` section.